# How to add splash screen from xcode 6 to ipad?

Tags: ios8, xcode6, ipad-2

I am using Xcode 6 .In my app i want to add slash screen.splash screen for 3 sec .give me step by step instruction .

Comment: Do you find your answer? because I have exactly this question too..

Comment: 640x960.png,640x1136.png,750x1334.png,768x1024.png,1024x768.png,1242x2208.png,1536x2048.png,2048x1536.png,2208x1242.png  create these image and in ganaral tab launch images drag and drop thses images.